# beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler doesn't expire

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios5

On connect i added this bit of code at the end of getting the user connected:

```
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier myLongTask;
    myLongTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
                  beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
                      //   If you're worried about exceeding 10 minutes, handle it here
                  }];

    CFRunLoopRun();
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:myLongTask];
```

I also set in build settings, application needs wifi. This is a basic client that uses a socket.

Before if i locked the iPad the internet died. Now i was expecting it to stay alive for 10 minutes after the iPad locks but for some reason it just stays on indefinitely so far. I've measured the internet being on over 30 minutes after i lock the phone and come back and unlock and my connection is still streaming chat.

I'm concerned this may not be legal app behavior for acceptance in app store though i did not set any special settings i was reading about that this is a VOIP app. I just used the beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler, and application requires internet.  I'm also concerned about long term battery impact if indeed the application never really sleeps, though the server i'm connecting to would disconnect you if idle for 60 minutes so it would not stay connected indefinitely but still its a concern if this loop always runs even after a disconnect it could use battery. For example what if the user leaves the app and doesnt come back for over a week and the iPad is just sitting locked for a week would it use accelerated battery? My testing hasn't got that far yet as this is a new situation this morning that i have were internet wont turn off were before it shut the connection any time the screen locked.

Any suggestions? Anyone know why the app wont sleep after 10 minutes of a screen lock?

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the os may kill you or it may not. the 10 minutes are more like a 'guideline' but the os may kill you earlier or later anyways.

but CFRunloopRun will run almost indevifinitly (well as long any source is attached or it is stopped). make sure it ends or you never end the bg task.

not forbidden but not cool!

Comment: i'm ok with it running indefinitely if it keeps internet alive but i was hoping after the iPad was idle for a prolong period of time it would die like if they locked their iPad and went to work or went to sleep.

Comment: see my edit.... the CFRunloop runs without end and you somehow seem to keep stuff alive :) look again at your code and what you do in it

Comment: the code is at the end of hitting connect.  it connects you then starts this.  the connect method would normally exit so i'm just forcing it not to exit but the full program is functional after. Its set to only do this teh first time they connect not any reconnects.  so its like at the end of a first connect i start a continuous thread but the full application appears to have a normal life and it's not stuck on any task. it gets data, you can send data and you can reconnect. there is just one long thread taks left running. my concern is battery which i'm measuring now.

Comment: measuring battery and on idle i'm losing a percent an hour it seems. i think this idea is going to get tossed at least how i'm doing it and i might explore the screen not locking while they use the program. at least then its only a high demand program when its used.

Comment: disable locking with application.idleTimer = NO;

Answer (score 0):

This is a very strange way to setup a background task request. It is unusual to call `CFRunLoopRun()` manually this way as well. The fact that you do this on the main loop suggests that you're not using the standard `UIApplicationMain()` function. If not, then you may not be setting up the application correctly, and behaviors can be erratic. Have you tried using background tasks the normal way:

- `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`
- Do the specific task you would like to run even if the program goes into the background
- `endBackgroundTask:` when that task is done

The way you're doing it, `endBackgroundTask:` is likely never called.

---

EDIT: If your goal is to be allowed to run after going into the background for as long as the OS is willing to let you run (around 10 minutes), then call `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` in `applicationWillEnterBackground:`. You don't need any special use of the runloop. You just need to tell the OS you'd like to keep going until it stops you.

Comment: my basic problem was how to define a telnet loop , it creates a socket and check for data seems to get called automatically, but how to define the telnet loop as a process that would be eliglbe for long task usage.  its not technically a start stop process. it simply runs while connected. i just havent figure out how to place the code to preserve the connection on screen lock and still known how to stop.  technically there is no reason a connection would need to drop in 10 minutes. the server wont kick you unless your idle an hour.

Comment: but i might just move to exploring the screen not locking when you have the program up to keep you connected. i never worked with screen lock code but i'd want it to be able to lock if you were not in the programs window anymore.

Comment: one of my testers is complaining about the connection dropping.  on hte ipod you get 5 minuts of idle and then lock or you elect the screen never turn off. this is the kind of program you may log in and watch chat, maybe you take ti to the tv room and turn on basketball, and have the servers sports channel on, but you get to watching your 5 minutes passes and you lost connection which breaks up the flow of chat. so maybe i will just work on the screen lock issue. better screen not lock when program is open then force people to choose no lock behavior.